# Pass custom Headers/Fields across trace calls using Application Insight agent(v3) and Java spring boot application

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-application-insights, trace

I've used Application insight v3.0 agent with my Java spring boot applications. There are two applications A and B running.
A is making an internal call to B.

Current Status:
I could see the transaction end to end in Application Insight portal in azure. With auogenerated operation_id, parent_id etc. fields.

What I want to achieve?
It is to pass a custom header/field like "OfferId" from frontend client that should be propogated across service calls and should be visible in the azure portal.

What I have tried so Far?
Based on the documentation avaialable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#correlation-headers-using-w3c-tracecontext.
I've tried with following headers
Correlation-Context
correlationcontext

But it dosen't seem to work. How to achieve this and what is the best practice around this.

To Note: My first priority is to achieve this in a codeless manner.

Comment: `Correlation-Context` is deprecated. Did you try `tracestate` which is the latest W3C standard as mentioned in [Correlation headers using W3C TraceContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#correlation-headers-using-w3c-tracecontext)? Also refer https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/. Example: tracestate: rojo=00f067aa0ba902b7,congo=t61rcWkgMzE